# What is the correct way to mock HttpClient and return an observable in angular unit testing?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have been working on this for an embarrassingly long period of time. I am trying to write a unit test for an angular app that mocks out HttpClient and returns an observable for the code being tested.

My test looks like this

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ProjectComponent ],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        HttpClient
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProjectComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    var service = TestBed.get(HttpClient);

    var obs = Observable.create( observer => {
      observer.next({'hi':'hi'});
      observer.complete();
    });
    spyOn(service, 'get').and.returnValue(obs);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

My code to test looks like this.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('starting');
    const x = this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/project')
      x.subscribe((response: any) => {
        console.log('$$$$$$');
        console.log(response);
        this.projects = response;
      }, e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }
```

As you can see I want the observable to be returned by the get method as a mocked response. If i debug the variable x in the ngOninit method I see that the observable comes in there. But the subscribe function is never called. What is the matter with this? How can I get the subscribe function to be called? Am I creating/mocking the observable in the wrong way? ... Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests, but note that a component typically shouldn't use the HttpClient directly - use a service to abstract away the details of the transport layer.

Comment: There are many articles to be found in this topic. You could perhaps start here: https://medium.com/netscape/testing-with-the-angular-httpclient-api-648203820712

Answer (score 0):

based on documentation you need to use `HttpTestingController` instead of spying `HttpClient`.

```js
    const httpMock: HttpTestingController = TestBed.get(
      HttpTestingController,
    );

    // Simulating a request.
    const req = httpMock.expectOne('http://localhost:8080/project');
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
    req.flush([false, true, false]);
    httpMock.verify();
```